# String escaping in generated html attribute jquery selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, protractor

I'd like to make a loop that assigns a variable to each of the 0-9 digit pads on a calculator. Here is what I would like to work:

```
var numpad = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    numpad[i] = $('[data-num="i"]');
}
```

Resulting in:

```
numPad[1] = $('[data-num="1"]');
numPad[2] = $('[data-num="2"]');
numPad[3] = $('[data-num="3"]');
etc...
```

I tried several variations of string escapes but nothing gave me the element.

Comment: Because `i` isn't considered a variable in the string ... it is a hard coded letter only. Concatenate it instead or for modern browsers can use *template literals*

Comment: That's what I was having trouble with. Mind sharing how I would do that? Thanks

Comment: `$('[data-num="' + i + '"]')`

Comment: Didn't try that variation. Thanks so much!

Comment: To be honest not sure why you would need to do this. The whole collection of `$('[data-num]')` can be easily indexed already from the jquery object